# Elasticsearch query to retrieve particular _source value for a particular type for all ID's

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch

Is there a way in CURL/JSON to retrieve the source values of a particular type for all the ID's that exists in the index? So for example, in the sample data below, I need to get the _id_batch (source value) for all the id's of the type (document). The _source_include works at the ID level but I wanted to retrieve all the values for _source_include for all the ID's of the type in the index.

Once I get there, I would then like to limit the data in the output so give me the _id_batch only for those records which have maybe something like, "location":"west palm beach".

Something like (* is just for example to select all the values):

```
curl -X GET "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/*/_source?_source_include=_id_batch" -d "
{
"from": 0,
"fields":[],
"size":50,
"sort":[]
}
" > "C:\Users\user\Downloads\output.json"
```

Sample Data:

URL: http://IPServer:9200/index_name/document

```
{
  "_index" : "<index_name>",
  "_type" : "document",
  "_id" : "11",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"_id_batch":1001688,"_id_document":11,"name":"xxx","location":"west palm beach","tweet":"0.0"}
}

{
  "_index" : "<index_name>",
  "_type" : "document",
  "_id" : "12",
  "_version" : 1,
  "found" : true,
  "_source":{"_id_batch":1001689,"_id_document":12,"name":"yyy","location":"west palm beach","tweet":"0.0"}
}
```

Expected Output:

```
{"_id_batch":1001688}
{"_id_batch":1001689}
```

Sample Query (using command line hence the ""):

```
curl -X GET "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/11/_source?_source_include=_id_batch" -d "
{
    "from": 0,
    "fields":[],
    "size":50,
    "sort":[]
}
" > "C:\Users\user\Downloads\output.json"
```

Sample Output in the JSON file:

```
{"_id_batch":1001688}
```

Tried the call -

```
curl -XPOST "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/_search" -d "{"query" : { "match_all" : {} },"size" : <LARGE_NUM>,"_source" : [ "_id_batch" ]}"
```

Got the Error -

```
{"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[dyYdbJLMQeC5XvXE0wwA9Q][<index_name>][0]: RemoteTransportException[[<server>][inet[/<IP Server>:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token '_id_batch': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 61]]; }{[dyYdbJLMQeC5XvXE0wwA9Q][<index_name>][1]: RemoteTransportException[[<server>][inet[/<IP Server>:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][1]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token '_id_batch': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 61]]; }{[31mSI_d3SPmTf7cU1dSNlQ][<index_name>][2]: RemoteTransportException[[D1-C04-WAPP02][inet[/<IP>:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][2]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token '_id_batch': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: 1, column: 61]]; }{[q2tWPLiCQR-O2zXRZBuQYg][<index_name>][3]: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][3]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token '_id_batch': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@4fccd33b; line: 1, column: 61]]; }{[q2tWPLiCQR-O2zXRZBuQYg][<index_name>][4]: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][4]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]]; nested: JsonParseException[Unrecognized token '_id_batch': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: [B@4fccd33b; line: 1, column: 61]]; }]","status":400}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
curl -XPOST "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/_search" -d '{
    "query" : { "match_all" : {} },
    "size" : <LARGE_NUM>,
    "_source" : [ "_id_batch" ]
}'
```

where LARGE_NUM is a large number >> count of all records of type 'document'

So you are specifying the type or mapping ('document') via the endpoint you are hitting and you are querying for all Elasticsearch records for that mapping.

Comment: I tried the same exact query above (of course by plugging in the correct values for the IP and Index name) before as well and it gave me the error here - error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed; shardFailures {[dyYdbJLMQeC5XvXE0wwA9Q][<index_name>][0]: RemoteTransportException[[SERVER][inet[/10.10.1.14:9300]][indices:data/read/search[phase/query]]]; nested: SearchParseException[[<index_name>][0]: query[ConstantScore(*:*)],from[-1],size[50]: Parse Failure [Failed to parse source [{query : { match_all : {} },size : 50,_source : [ _id_batch ]}]]];

Comment: How did you try it?  Using curl?  Can you please post the full and exact curl response { "error" : "...", "status" : 4xx } if you tried the curl (but cut out anything unnecessary like index name, etc)?  This is a pretty simply query and I am not exactly sure what that error is if you got that via the curl request described.

Comment: This was my CURL call which I ran from CMD, I would post the error above since the comment section does not allow more than 500 characters - curl -XPOST "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/_search" -d "{"query" : { "match_all" : {} },"size" : 50,"_source" : [ "_id_batch" ]}"

Comment: Nevermind, I just realized that since I am trying it from CMD it would need another double quotes around _id_batch so it should be something like - curl -XPOST "http://<IP Server>:9200/<index_name>/document/_search" -d "{"query" : { "match_all" : {} },"size" : 50,"_source" : [ ""_id_batch"" ]}"